# Analog to Pandas Series.value_counts() in R?

Tags: r, pandas, dplyr

In `Python`, one can get the counts of values in a list by using `Series.value_counts()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = ['a','b','b','c','c','d']
df['y'] = list(range(1,7))

df['x'].value_counts()

c    2
b    2
a    1
d    1
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

In `R`, I have to use three separate commands.

```
df <- tibble(x=c('a','b','b','c','c','d'), y=1:6)

df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% arrange(desc(n))

x   n
b   2
c   2
a   1
d   1
```

Is there a shorter / more idiomatic way of doing this in R? Or am I better off writing a custom function?

Comment: `dplyr::count(df, x, sort = TRUE)`

Comment: what about `table(df$x)`

Comment: Thanks @rpolicastro, that's what I was looking for! If you submit I can mark as answer.

Comment: Glad I could help! I submitted an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The tidyverse has `dplyr::count`, which is a shortcut for 'group_by' and 'summarize' to get counts.

```
df <- tibble(x=c('a','b','b','c','c','d'), y=1:6)

dplyr::count(df, x, sort = TRUE)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  x         n
  <chr> <int>
1 b         2
2 c         2
3 a         1
4 d         1
```